# index to class return in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have implemented class to index.
That is when I call (_class_to_ind) with class name, index wrt to the class is returned.

```
_classes = ('__background__', 'plate', 'one', 'two')
_class_to_ind = dict(zip(_classes, xrange(_classes)))
```

Now is I like to make it reverse as

```
_classes = ('__background__', 'plate', 'one', 'two')
_ind_to_classes = ???????????
```

When I call `_ind_to_classes(1)`, I have return class.
How can i do that?
I prefer python2.7.

Comment: Did you try reversing the arguments of `zip`?

Comment: let me test, thanks

Comment: If you're saying "how can I pass in `1` and get the element at index 1 of `_classes`?", why not just regular indexing: `_classes[1]`?

Comment: you might as well add `xrange(len(_classes)) #notice the len` or else it would throw `TypeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this

`_class_to_ind = dict(zip(xrange(len(_classes)), _classes))`

the output was

`_class_to_ind[1] >> 'plate'`

is this what you are looking for?